# Highlight range of cells and press button to run macro only for that range

Tags: excel, replace, vba

I am trying to select and highlight a range of cells in column A, and then press the button to run the macro to find and replace all "NL" occurrences to "N".

So far this only works if I select one cell but not entire selected range.

```
Sub ReplaceAll_NL()

 ActiveCell.Select
 Selection.Replace What:="NL", Replacement:="N", LookAt:=xlPart, _
     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
     ReplaceFormat:=False
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your macro to use the `Selection` that the user has chosen, don't change the `Selection` within the macro to be something different:

```
Sub ReplaceAll_NL()    
    'ActiveCell.Select '<-- This line was changing the selection to be something
                       '    different to what the user had selected.

    Selection.Replace What:="NL", Replacement:="N", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```